# What are the holes in a circular saw rip fence intended for

Tags: circular-saw, fence

I have a rip fence on my circular saw similar to the one here. What are the holes for? Can I add a longer piece of metal / wood to extend the fence? Wouldn't that then make the measurements on the fence inaccurate?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The holes are so you can attach a straight longer piece of wood to it.

Answer (score 2):

It will affect the distance, but you can gain accuracy.  Measure and mark is always safer than using the measurements on the gauge.